# Is my proof correct? are the arguments right?

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, proof-verification, weak-convergence

my assumptions:

(i) $\lim_{t \to \infty}F_{t}(x)=F(x) \ \forall\ x\ \in\ C(F)$(set of continuity points of F) with $F_{t}(x)$ family of distribution functions and $F$ distribution function

(ii)
$\lim_{t \to \infty}x_{t}=x_{0}$ ($x_{0}\in C(F)$)

this we can write as: $\forall\ \epsilon>0\ \exists T$ such that $|x_{t}-x_{0}|<\epsilon$ for $t>T$

i want to show that then also the following statement is valid:

$\lim_{t \to \infty}F_{t}(x_{t}) =F(x_{0})$

My proof

first i`m looking for an upper bound of $F_{t}(x_{t})$:

$F_{t}(x_{t})=P_{t}(X_{t}\leq x_{t})\leq P_{t}(X_{t}\leq \epsilon+x_{0}) $ for t sufficient large

with the help of this upper bound we know that there exists the limsup of $F_{t}(x_{t})$ such that
$\limsup_{t \to \infty}F_{t}(x_{t})\leq F(x_{0}+\epsilon)$ an because of the right continuity of F and as we can choose $\epsilon$ very small we get 
$\limsup_{t \to \infty}F_{t}(x_{t})\leq F(x_{0})$

When i go the same way to get a lower bound i will get

$F(x_{0})\leq \liminf_{t \to \infty}F_{t}(x_{t})$ and as we know that both exist and valid the following unequality

$F(x_{0})\leq \liminf_{t \to \infty} F_{t}(x_{t})\leq  \limsup_{t \to \infty}F_{t}(x_{t})\leq F(x_{0})$

they must be equal and so it is done.

second try (here i try an other way and i think on this way there is no problem with the missing left continuity)

$F$ continuity in $x_{0}$ then the following inequality is valid:

$F(x_{0})-\epsilon<F(x)<F(x_{0})+\epsilon \ \forall x \mbox{with}\|x-x_{0}|<\delta$ but then there exists also continuity points $x_{1},x_{2}$ mit $x_{1}<x_{0}<x_{2}$ such that

$F(x_{0})-\epsilon<F(x_{1})\leq F(x_{0})\leq F(x_{2})<F(x_{0})+\epsilon $
applying assumption (i) we get

$F(x_{0})-\epsilon<F_{t}(x_{1})\leq F_{t}(x_{0})\leq F_{t}(x_{2})<F(x_{0})+\epsilon $

And we know for t sufficiently large $x_{t} \in (x_{1},x_{2})$ so we get

$F(x_{0})-\epsilon<F_{t}(x_{1})\leq F_{t}(x_{t})\leq F_{t}(x_{2})<F(x_{0})+\epsilon $

Is it necessary to work with limsup and liminf? i think on this way it is not, because now we can choose $\epsilon$ small and get

$F_{t}(x_{0})\leq F_{t}(x_{t})\leq F_{t}(x_{0})$

Comment: You are on the right track. I should choose the $\varepsilon>0$ in such a way that $x_{0}+\varepsilon\in C\left(F\right)$
so that $\lim_{t\rightarrow\infty}F_{t}\left(x_{0}+\epsilon\right)=F\left(x_{0}+\epsilon\right)$. Change $P_t$ into $P$.

Comment: A much simpler proof is with Dini's theorem which states that $F_t$ converges uniformly to $F$.

Comment: thanks for the idea, but i need to show it without using any other special theorem,
is my way wrong?or am i missing to much arguments?